# Sed or String Replace command in Unix to change last First Character after Sequence to UpperCase

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, replace, sed

I basically have these xml files where I need to change the first alphabet after

Eg. 
Result:

I tried: `sed 's/<structure name=\"/\U\/g'`

However, this changes the entire word to uppercase. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`\U`** is for converting all characters. You will need to use **`\u`** to convert the first occurrence.

Also, you will need to group them to ensure correct letter is converted:

```
sed 's/\(<structure name=\"\)\(.\)/\1\u\2/' xml-file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/<structure name=\"\(.\)/<structure name=\"\U\1/'
```

`sed` will only convert strings being substituted to uppercase. We can use a capturing group to only convert the first character after the sequence to uppercase.

Otherwise, you can also use `\E`, which is similar to `\U`, except it stops converting characters instead of starting it.